# Add DNS local entry

Tags: networking, dns

I have a local server 192.168.1.10 (I attached DNS record locally to HTTP://inventory.local) In the local network I use this service perfectly.

Today, I decided to connect to the local network via VPN, and unfortunately, I got the error: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. I add the DNS record to /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.1.10    http://inventory.local
```

It does not solve the issue, but I can ping IP 192.168.1.10 and host http://inventory.local. In my case browser can't use this record.

How to configure ubuntu to use a local site via VPN?

Comment: What VPN are you using? The VPN may be using its own DNS.

Comment: I use an L2TP connection, I set up a VPN on my ZYXEL router and added this record on this router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http://`, and its encrypted variation `https://`, is a protocol prefix for the [Hypertext Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) or `HTTP`. It doesn't belong to the [Domain Name System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) or `DNS`, to a [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) or any other way of name resolution.

Therefore, the entry in your `/etc/hosts` needs to be something like

```
192.168.1.10    inventory.local
```

There may be additional problems, but a `http://` prefix doesn't belong in a `hosts` file in any case ;)